# InsertImage in HtmlEditorExtender show blank box

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net-4.0, ajaxcontroltoolkit

HtmlEditorExtender control when trying to upload an image (locally or on server) shows me a blank, does not show me the controls to upload the images, even the button close / cancel

[image]

Environment:
VS2010 Framework 4.0,
AjaxToolKit.dll 4.1.7.123,
HtmlAgilityPack.dll 1.4.0.0,
SanitizerProviders.dll 1.0.0.0,
IIS 7

**ASP**:

```
<asp:HtmlEditorExtender ID="HtmlEditorExtender_Nota" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static"
TargetControlID="txtNota" DisplaySourceTab="true" OnImageUploadComplete="saveFile" >
    <Toolbar>
        <asp:Undo />
        <asp:Redo />
        <asp:HorizontalSeparator />

        <asp:Bold />
        <asp:Italic />
        <asp:Underline />
        <asp:StrikeThrough />

        <asp:HorizontalSeparator />
        <asp:Subscript />
        <asp:Superscript />

        <asp:HorizontalSeparator />
        <asp:JustifyLeft />
        <asp:JustifyCenter />
        <asp:JustifyRight />
        <asp:JustifyFull />
        <asp:Indent />
        <asp:Outdent />
        <asp:InsertHorizontalRule />

        <asp:HorizontalSeparator />
        <asp:InsertOrderedList />
        <asp:InsertUnorderedList />

        <asp:HorizontalSeparator />
        <asp:CreateLink />
        <asp:UnLink />

        <asp:HorizontalSeparator />
        <asp:SelectAll />
        <asp:UnSelect />

        <asp:HorizontalSeparator />
        <asp:RemoveFormat />
        <asp:Delete />
        <asp:Cut />
        <asp:Copy />
        <asp:Paste />

        <asp:HorizontalSeparator />
        <asp:FontNameSelector />
        <asp:FontSizeSelector />
        <asp:BackgroundColorSelector />
        <asp:ForeColorSelector />

        <asp:HorizontalSeparator />
        <asp:InsertImage />
    </Toolbar>
<asp:HtmlEditorExtender>
```

**Codebehind**:

```
/// <summary>
/// SaveImagen HtmlEditorExtender AjaxControl
/// </summary>
/// <param name="sender"></param>
/// <param name="e"></param>
protected void saveFile(object sender, AjaxControlToolkit.AjaxFileUploadEventArgs e)
{
    if (!Directory.Exists(MapPath(_fileImgNotasPath)))
        Directory.CreateDirectory(MapPath(_fileImgNotasPath));

    // Generate file path
    string filePath = _fileImgNotasPath;
    filePath += HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name + "_";
    filePath += String.Format("{0:ddMMyyyyhhmm}", DateTime.Now);
    filePath += e.FileName.Substring(e.FileName.Length - 4, 4);

    // Save uploaded file to the file system
    var ajaxFileUpload = (AjaxFileUpload)sender;
    ajaxFileUpload.SaveAs(MapPath(filePath));

    // Update client with saved image path
    e.PostedUrl = Page.ResolveUrl(filePath);
}
```

**WebConfig**

```
<system.web>
    ...
    <sanitizer defaultProvider="HtmlAgilityPackSanitizerProvider">
        <providers>
            <add name="HtmlAgilityPackSanitizerProvider" type="AjaxControlToolkit.Sanitizer.HtmlAgilityPackSanitizerProvider"/>
        </providers>
    </sanitizer>
    ...
</system.web>
```

**References added, dll in bin folder**

This worked, at some point stopped working, and update the AjaxToolKit and nothing. **All other controls work** :S nothing more that part of InsertImage
What could be happening?

help me superman!! ;)

Answer (score 2):

Your are using `<asp:Bold />` instead of  `<ajaxToolkit:Bold />`

Replace all of your asp tags with the ajaxtoolkit.

```
<Toolbar> 
        <ajaxToolkit:Undo />
        <ajaxToolkit:Redo />
        <ajaxToolkit:Bold />
        <ajaxToolkit:Italic />
        <ajaxToolkit:Underline />
        <ajaxToolkit:StrikeThrough />
        <ajaxToolkit:Subscript />
        <ajaxToolkit:Superscript />
        <ajaxToolkit:JustifyLeft />
        <ajaxToolkit:JustifyCenter />
        <ajaxToolkit:JustifyRight />
        <ajaxToolkit:JustifyFull />
        <ajaxToolkit:InsertOrderedList />
        <ajaxToolkit:InsertUnorderedList />
        <ajaxToolkit:CreateLink />
        <ajaxToolkit:UnLink />
        <ajaxToolkit:RemoveFormat />
        <ajaxToolkit:SelectAll />
        <ajaxToolkit:UnSelect />
        <ajaxToolkit:Delete />
        <ajaxToolkit:Cut />
        <ajaxToolkit:Copy />
        <ajaxToolkit:Paste />
        <ajaxToolkit:BackgroundColorSelector />
        <ajaxToolkit:ForeColorSelector />
        <ajaxToolkit:FontNameSelector />
        <ajaxToolkit:FontSizeSelector />
        <ajaxToolkit:Indent />
        <ajaxToolkit:Outdent />
        <ajaxToolkit:InsertHorizontalRule />
        <ajaxToolkit:HorizontalSeparator />
        <ajaxToolkit:InsertImage />
</Toolbar>
```

And in your HTMLEditorExtender tag, give an Id and use `OnImageUploadComplete` to call your function.

```
<ajaxToolkit:HtmlEditorExtender
    id="MyHtmlEditorExtender"
    TargetControlID="txtComments"
    OnImageUploadComplete="MyHtmlEditorExtender_ImageUploadComplete"
    DisplaySourceTab="true"
    runat="server" >
    <Toolbar>
        <ajaxToolkit:Bold />
        <ajaxToolkit:Italic />
        <ajaxToolkit:Underline />
        <ajaxToolkit:InsertImage />
    </Toolbar>
</ajaxToolkit:HtmlEditorExtender>
```

In code behind,

```
using System.Web.UI;
using AjaxControlToolkit;

namespace WebApplication1
{
    public partial class ImageUpload : System.Web.UI.Page
    {

        protected void MyHtmlEditorExtender_ImageUploadComplete(object sender, AjaxFileUploadEventArgs e)
        {
            // Generate file path
            string filePath = "~/Images/" + e.FileName;

            // Save uploaded file to the file system
            var ajaxFileUpload = (AjaxFileUpload)sender;
            ajaxFileUpload.SaveAs(MapPath(filePath));

            // Update client with saved image path
            e.PostedUrl = Page.ResolveUrl(filePath);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I Record AjaxToolKit with the prefix "asp" instead of "ajaxToolKit" (webconfig).
the Event is in the asp control and the codebehind
     <pages>
      <controls>
        <add tagPrefix="asp" namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" />
        <add tagPrefix="asp" namespace="System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting"
          assembly="System.Web.DataVisualization, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
      </controls>
    </pages>